# Embedding data from another document in Cosmos DB

Tags: microservices, azure-cosmosdb

When embedding data from another document in another collection, what is the best practice as to who should be responsible to populate that data in a microservice architecture?

As an example, let's say I have basic information about an organization:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "legalName": "Initech"
}
```

which I want to embed in an invoice like this to avoid doing two service requests to show the invoice:

```
{
      "type": "Payable",
      "invoiceStatus": "Preparing Preliminary Version",
      "applicablePeriod": {
        "startDateTime": "2020-07-08T00:10:59.618Z",
        "endDateTime": "2020-07-08T00:10:59.618Z"
      },
      "issuedDateTime": "2020-07-08T00:10:59.618Z"
      "issuingOrganization":{
             "id": 1,
             "legalName": "Initech"
       }
}
```

Would it be the caller's responsibility to supply the data while creating/updating the invoice or would it be the invoice service that would retrieve the external data using the organization id and then embed the data as necessary?

I feel like I should avoid having cross service dependencies in the backend as much as possible. I understand the maintenance of the embedded data could be achieved through the change feed but I was wondering about the initial population of the embedded data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get an answer back on this? I at least, wanted to provide an answer to serve as general guidance. It comes down to the state of the data. Please see the following document which covers this specific topic in greater detail: [Data modeling in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data)

> In general, use embedded data models when ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data#when-to-embed)):
>
> - There are **contained** relationships between entities.
> - There are **one-to-few** relationships between entities.
> - There is embedded data that **changes infrequently**.
> - There is embedded data that will not grow **without bound**.
> - There is embedded data that is **queried frequently together**.
>
> Embedding data works nicely for many cases but there are scenarios when denormalizing your data will cause more problems than it is worth. So what do we do now?

> When to reference ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data#when-to-reference)):
>
> In general, use normalized data models when:
>
> - Representing **one-to-many** relationships.
> - Representing **many-to-many** relationships.
> - Related data **changes frequently**.
> - Referenced data could be **unbounded**.

> Hybrid data models ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data#hybrid-data-models)).

> We've now looked embedding (or denormalizing) and referencing (or normalizing) data, each have their upsides and each have compromises as we have seen.
>
> It doesn't always have to be either or, don't be scared to mix things up a little.
>
> Based on your application's specific usage patterns and workloads there may be cases where mixing embedded and referenced data makes sense and could lead to simpler application logic with fewer server round trips while still maintaining a good level of performance.

So, with the above Data Model information, the other half of the equation is [Identifying microservice boundaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/model/microservice-boundaries) and [designing a microservices architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/design/) but, in a simpler scenario...the invoice service would perform an [update to the root document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/documentdb-adds-upsert/), either through embedding the invoice or linking the invoice.